# How to insert data in my table in wordpress if a category of current post is selected?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to check if the current post is belongs to a category then insert some data in a table (already created) if a term selected.

In human readable format, I was expecting to do something like this:

If Education category selected, insert "data" in table requests

I've tried this code but I've nothing registered in my table

```
global $wpdb, $current_user;
           get_currentuserinfo();
           $uid = $current_user->ID;
           $pid = $_GET['auction_id'];
           $tm = current_time('timestamp',0);
           $auction_cat = wp_get_object_terms($pid, 'auction_cat');
           $cate = array($auction_cat[0]->term_id);

    // check if the category of auction is University_Id = 4

        if (in_array(4, $cate))
        {
        $wpdb->query("insert into ".$wpdb->prefix."auction_requests (pid, uid, datemade) values('$pid','$uid',$tm')");  
            }
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance